# Show that $2^n>1+n\sqrt{2^{n-1}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, convex-analysis

> If $n$ be a positive integer greater than $1$, then prove that $$2^n>1+n\sqrt{2^{n-1}}$$

I found this problem under $AM \ge GM$ chapter. Help me to solve this problem using  $AM \ge GM$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hint:$1+2+2^2+\dots 2^{n-1}=2^n-1$

**Edit:**

Solution:

> Applying A.M.-G.M. on $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^{k}$ we have $2^n-1=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^{k}\ge n(2^{(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k)})^{\frac{1}{n}}=n2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$

Comment: Again you beat me :) (+1)

Comment: Really???@O.L. Thank by the way...

Comment: It almost hurts for its simplicity. +1

Comment: @ Abhra Abir Kundu:$\large{+1}$

Comment: Thank you for helping me. This is the best answer for this question.

Comment: @A.D You are welcome.... and thanks for this complement ..

Comment: @A.D I think you are correct, considering it's the only answer. (tongue in cheek)