# If n is a positive integer, then prove that $2^n \gt 1 + n\;\sqrt{{2}^{n-1}}$ ; $n\gt 1$

Tags: inequality

I tried using A.M. $\ge$ G.M. and Mathematical Induction, but couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $2^n>1+n\sqrt{2^{n-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424396/show-that-2n1n-sqrt2n-1)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2478361/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a^n-1=(a-1)\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}a^r$$

Now Apply AM $\ge$ GM

For $a>1$

$$\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}a^r}n>\sqrt[n]{\prod_{r=0}^{n-1}a^r}=\sqrt[n]{a^{\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}r}}$$

the equality is excluded as each of $a^r,0\le r\le n-1$ is different